# Can not send data with XMLHttpRequest on same php page

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send the hallID using the XMLHttpRequest on the SAME php page so I can display the hall details in the modal window.

PHP code (in the middle of the page)

```
    foreach ($halls as $hall) {
        if ($schedule['hallID'] == $hall['hallID']) {
        echo "<a class='hallID' data-toggle='modal' href='#largeModal' data-id='".$schedule['hallID']."' onclick='sendId(".$schedule['hallID'].");'>". $hall['hallName']."</a>";
        }
    }
```

Javascript function: (on the bottom of the page, after the php code ends)

```
function sendId(hallID) { 
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  
                console.log('And here the value of the hallID is :' +hallID); // <<<<<<<<<< this code is never excecuted
            }
        };
        var url = "http://localhost/"+location.pathname;
        xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("hallID="+hallID);
        alert(hallID); // <<<<<<<<<< correct ID is alerted
    }
```

However my $_POST is always empty. The var_dump($_POST) returns array(0) { }

Comment: try to print tha address (then copy-paste it to browser) and see what error the server gives you: `alert(url)`;

Comment: I just did that, and the url is correct.

Comment: try to plot the content of the plain request in php `$request = file_get_contents("php://input"); echo $request;` (withput having it automatically parsed by php).

Comment: I placed both lines after the var_dump($_POST), nothing. Nothing is printed.

Comment: Probably you have an error in the address (location.pathname) check that or in the binding of your php handler

Comment: as far as for the url, I have copy & paste the url and tried that way, but no results. I did not understand the part related with binding of the php handler. can you elaborate?